# Automatic deployment on git push

Tags: deployment, yii2, continuous-integration, composer-php, gitlab

How to configure automatic deployment of yii2 project to production server on gitlab push?

I found 2 related things: webhooks and gitlab-ci. If I understand correctly, when using webhooks webserver has to have write access to project folder, which is bad. Tried to configure gitlab-ci with private runner on server, but failed.

There are 3 items in repo root folder: .gitlab-ci.yml file and src folder and .git folder.

```
#.gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd ./src && composer install
  only:
    - prod
```

There is a [yii2 basic](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-from-composer) project in src folder.

About in 3 minutes after I push to prod branch I am recieving email with message "Pipeline has succeded". But files in server's folder are not updating. I found that somewhere in /home/gitlab-runner/.. folder tree there is a copy of project. But I need to update files in specific folder. So, where and how to configure that folder?

Comment: In the email that says the Pipeline has succeeded, can you click the link to go to the build log? That probably has some information that would be useful for debugging this.

Comment: @ConnorShea, yes, build log looks like console output and it helps very much during configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by experimenting:

```
#.gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - composer --no-interaction --no-progress --prefer-dist --working-dir=src install
    - cp -Rf ${CI_PROJECT_DIR} /path/on/server/
  only:
    - prod
```

Besides this I added gitlab-runner user to web server user group. On ubuntu server using this command:

```
sudo chmod g+w -R /path/on/server
sudo usermod -a -G www-data gitlab-runner
```

I am open to any suggestions.